# Size of a geometric point

Tags: geometry, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

It is well known that the geometric points do not have any length, area, volume, or any other dimensional attribute, also geometric object (for example "line") is made up of a infinite number of geometric point.

Does geometric point have any dimension $h$?

Where $h$ is some hyperreal number and $st($h$)=0$

Comment: You don't consider points to have dimension $0$?

Comment: I can't think of a definition where hyperreal dimensions would make any kind of sense.

Comment: I think zero is an infinitesimal object  which is smaller than any feasible measurement, but NOT zero in size.